# Summing nested lists in Python (not only int)

Tags: python, recursion, sum, nested-lists

i got this task today from school to make a function Sum(list):
i researched and found out few ways how to make it work with list that consist of int, or list of list of integers, however my function should work also with other types like string, or tuples. Here are some examples of what it should do.

```
Sum([1,2,3]) returns 6;  Sum([2,[1.5,3],0.5]) returns 7.0;
Sum([[['p'],'yt'],['h',['on']]]) returns 'python'
Sum([[(1,2)],(3,),[(4,5)]])  returns (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

And on top of that all it should be also able to compute if argument in the function Sum(X) is NOT list. Example:

```
Sum(5*5) returns 25;
```

This is what i am working with so far, works fine for first 2 cases, however i cant find a way to modify it to work for other examples. Personaly ive been trying to use isinstance and exceptions

```
def list_sum(L):
    total = 0  
    for i in L:
        if isinstance(i, list): 
            total += list_sum(i)
        else:
            total += i
    return total
```

Many thanks for any kind of help

Comment: what about `list_sum([(3,(4,8))])`? or `list_sum([((4,8),(3,2))])`?

Comment: Should return (3,4,8) and (4,8,3,2) if thats what you ask

Answer (score 1):

Use the first non-list value as the *initial* value for the sum. Let `None` signify that we did not yet see such value:

```
def list_sum(L):
    if not isinstance(L, list):
        return L

    total = None
    for i in L:
        i = list_sum(i)

        if total is None:
            total = i
        else:
            total += i
    return total
```

Also, in this case, using `isinstance` is the sanest thing to do.

---

For the really robust case that handles empty lists correctly, make use of a [flattening generator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2158532/918959):

```
def list_sum(l):
    def flatten(l):
        for el in l:
            if isinstance(el, list):
                for sub in flatten(el):
                    yield sub
            else:
                yield el

    if isinstance(l, list):
        return sum(flatten(l))
    return l
```

Note that the builtin `sum` function works in that case.

Comment: Awesome, works like a clock for first part of the problem. Many thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner for doing this with just integers, for future reference:

```
from itertools import chain as flatten

def nested_sum(l):
    return sum(flatten.from_iterable(l))
```

`itertools.chain` is great for flattening nested iterables.